# Write a program that prints the following: 100 99 98 ... 0 99 98 97 ... 0 all the way to 3 2 1 0 ... 2 1 0 ...1 0... 0 in processing

Tags: loops, processing

The code I have right now is:

```
int startsAt = 100;
while (startsAt > 0) {
    for (int i = 100; i>=startsAt; i-=1) {
        print(i + " ");
    }
    println("");
    startsAt -=1;
}
```

It prints it backwards. From *100* at the beginning to *100 99 98...0*

Answer (score 0):

```
int startsAt = 100;
for (int i = startsAt; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = i; j>=0; j-=1) {
        print(j + " ");
    }
    println("");
}
```

Comment: Not a bad answer! Though it's a fairly small bit of code, it would be helpful to include a little bit of context regarding why you would use a nested `for` loop in this case.